# Parquet Binary storing value in encoded format

Tags: java, parquet

I'm creating a parquet file from Java using org.apache.parquet.*. No issues with other data types, but when a binary value is written and I cat the parquet file using parquet-tools, it is showing the value in encoded format. Because of that, the parquet is not processed in my system further.

Code block:

```
case BINARY:
recordConsumer.addBinary(stringToBinary(val));
break;
        
AND
        
private Binary stringToBinary(Object value) {
return Binary.fromString(value.toString());
}
```

Schema used is:

```
message m { 
required INT64 id; 
required binary username; 
required boolean active; 
}
```

When I cat:

```
parquet-tools cat <parquetFileName>
```

I see something like this:

```
id = 1
username = TmFtZTE=
active = true

id = 2
username = TmFtZTI=
active = false
```

I want to see the actual Username passed and not the encoded strings.

Comment: Are you using the java parquet-tools (http://www.mtitek.com/tutorials/bigdata/hadoop/parquet-tools.php) or the python version (https://pypi.org/project/parquet-tools/)? Is there a reason to use binary instead of utf-8 strings for the username?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your schema
required binary username (UTF8)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).